# Check if given pattern is generated by Regex

Tags: regex, performance, algorithm, pattern-matching

I have a Regular expression and a pattern string to be matched.I need to check if the pattern is a **valid string generated by regex.**

Now the questions becomes interesting because,**the regex can contain only ' * ' character**,and a pre-defined letter set(a-z) .

Here **' * '** has meaning :

```
if regex is "a*": its closure { '','a','aa','aaa',.. }
if its "ab*c" : its closure { 'ac','abc','abbc', ... }
```

**Now,there is a backtracking solution to it ,checking all possibilities.**

I was wondering ,that since `we only have " * " as a special symbol`,can we do it in a better complexity .

Comment: generated or matched?

Comment: i just have to match,not generate.

Comment: [yes. much better complexity](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/)

Comment: @m.buettner: perhaps an explanation wud be better.

Comment: @Spandan sorry, I can't summarize it at the moment. just have a look at the first paper. it doesn't take too long reading and explains the trick really well.

Answer (score 0):

> Can we do it in a better complexity?

Yes. Just omit the backtracking, you have no alternations that would need them. Only you will have to normalize your regexes:

1. change all occurences of `X*X` to `XX*`
2. change all occurences of `X*X*` to `X*`

This can be done in linear complexity (in respect to the regex length); then you can just loop trough the input string in a single pass (with linear complexity in regard to the input length).